# I'm new to Unreal, and I'm trying to make a physics based game using CableActor. However, my actors explode as soon as I start a simulation

Tags: physics, unreal, unreal-5

Here's a video of what's happening:

https://youtu.be/5uckTbNTGHI

The cable starts swinging wildly, and the actors at the end of the cable fly off into infinity. Ideally when I start the simulation I want everything to be still at the start of the simulation.

I have tried to follow this guide:

https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/Physics/PhysicsAssetEditor/HowTo/FixCommonPhysicsErrors/

Ultimately I intend for the character to interact with the actor at the end of the cable component.

How can I resolve this explosion? Is it even an explosion?